# Bitcoin-abc node seems not connect to bch testnet

Tags: bitcoin-testnet, bitcoin-abc

I tried latest version(v.0.19.6) and v0.18.5, but both seems have different views from what is shown on bitcoin.com testnet explorer and latest height from bitcoin-abc always around 100 blocks ahead of what is shown on bitcoin.com explorer

for example, below is what I get using rpc call from bitcoin-abc for block at height 1306255:

```
{
    "bits": "1b3037a6",
    "chainwork": "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004c90a4d396ee6583d7",
    "confirmations": 57,
    "difficulty": 1359,
    "hash": "00000000002b9e83a7f55211bdb847b58ad7f37fae879478f9e32f8e75e6c9b4",
    "height": 1306255,
    "mediantime": 1559185963,
    "merkleroot": "088f104ca41a7ca4f83d6de267a85724dc0283aefc27d7ae978badcd571d40c0",
    "nextblockhash": "0000000000066ba2e8a751149138dc3a1be8168ea85fab1bc398ff3fbb9307e2",
    "nonce": 1464894606,
    "previousblockhash": "000000000020127e583624c682c96efb50cd56fc189928de917faba96a9c3d40",
    "size": 201,
    "time": 1559188014,
    "tx": [{
        "blockhash": "00000000002b9e83a7f55211bdb847b58ad7f37fae879478f9e32f8e75e6c9b4",
        "blocktime": 1559188014,
        "confirmations": 57,
        "hash": "088f104ca41a7ca4f83d6de267a85724dc0283aefc27d7ae978badcd571d40c0",
        "hex": "01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff23038fee1300fefc980800fefb2308000963676d696e6572343208040000000000000000ffffffff01c817a804000000001976a9146db2250c113ad124a60e0a522faef0b7f0c8b0ed88ac00000000",
        "locktime": 0,
        "size": 120,
        "time": 1559188014,
        "txid": "088f104ca41a7ca4f83d6de267a85724dc0283aefc27d7ae978badcd571d40c0",
        "version": 1,
        "vin": [{
            "sequence": 4294967295
        }],
        "vout": [{
            "addressValid": true,
            "n": 0,
            "scriptPubKey": {
                "addresses": ["bchtest:qpkmyfgvzyadzf9xpc99ytaw7zmlpj9sa5qrn24u9t"],
                "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 6db2250c113ad124a60e0a522faef0b7f0c8b0ed OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
                "hex": "76a9146db2250c113ad124a60e0a522faef0b7f0c8b0ed88ac",
                "reqSigs": 1,
                "type": "pubkeyhash"
            },
            "value": 0.78125
        }]
    }],
    "version": 536870912,
    "versionHex": "20000000"
}
```

while the bitcoin.com shows following for same height of 1306255 (even the block hash is different):
https://explorer.bitcoin.com/tbch/block/0000000000000340762ba9648a982a18442ff7423e787d4115da323a399dc57b

I am not sure what cause the problem, below is my conf:

```
server=1
daemon=1
txindex=1
logtimestamps=1

rpcuser=xxx
rpcpassword=xxxx
rpcport=18332
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0

datacarriersize=80

regtest=0
testnet=1
```

and I start bitcoin-abc node using following cmd:

```
bin/bitcoind -conf=/data/xxx-bch-test/bitcoin.conf -datadir=/data/xxx-bch-test/testnet -testnet &
```

and I noticed there is a log in debug.log not sure if it is related:

```
2019-05-30T11:33:56Z ERROR: AcceptBlockHeader: block 000000000000003a3fb0ca1611035346a803e0344d6bb2eb4f5ea75f4dc2291c is marked invalid
2019-05-30T11:33:56Z ERROR: invalid header received
```

but the hash looks good in bitcoin.com explorer

Comment: since the last match block #1303885, and all following block are mismatch for bitcoin-abc rpc node and bitcoin.com explorer

Comment: guess it is due to the may 15th upgrade and I will try with latest 0.19.6 to re-pull all blocks from genesis

Answer (score 0):

use latest 0.19.6 to re-pull all blocks from genesis works for me